# How to set background color based on cell position?

Tags: pandas

I need to set the background color in a dataframe based on the cell's position, not by the contents of the cell.

Consider this dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
```

Desired result, apologies for excel screen capture:

[image: apologies for the excel screen cap]

I want choose particular range of cells based on their position:

```
bg_color_range = df.loc[1:3,'B':'C']
```

And set their background to green:

```
def bg_green(x):
    return 'background-color: lime'

df.style.applymap(bg_green, bg_color_range)
```

But that gives `KeyError: "None of [Index(['B'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"` and I'm not sure how to tell `.style.applymap` what range of cells to operate on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [`subset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Finer-control:-slicing) argument of `applymap` with a `pd.IndexSlice` like:

```
df.style.applymap(bg_green, subset=pd.IndexSlice[1:3, 'B':'C'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `apply` with `axis=None`:

```
def bg_green(df):
    ret = pd.DataFrame('', index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
    ret.loc[1:3, 'B':'C'] = 'background-color: lime'
    return ret

df.style.apply(bg_green, axis=None)
```

Output:

[image]